# NLTK is not working on python after installation

Tags: python, nltk

I installed NLTK, numpy and matplotlib but whenever I try running any code after importing NLTK an error appears saying that nltk is not a package.
It doesn't give me any errors when i import nltk, it all happens after trying to import a text or a corpus.

- I already downloaded the library
  **note I also tried on python shell, still not working**

  > > > import nltk
  > > > from nltk.book import text1
  > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
  > > > File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in 
  > > > from nltk.book import text1
  > > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk.book'; 'nltk' is not a package

Comment: Is it possible that you have a file called `nltk.py` in the directory you run your code? That might cause this problem, remove or rename that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nltk` library does not come by default with the corpses. You have to download these after importing nltk to access `nltk.book`

Try the following -

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

This will prompt you to download the relevant package contents, one of which is the `nltk.book` that you are looking for -

```
NAME
    nltk

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    align
    app (package)
    book
    ccg (package)
    chat (package)
    chunk (package)
    classify (package)
    cluster (package)
    collocations
    corpus (package)
    data
    decorators
    downloader
    draw (package)
    examples (package)
    featstruct
    grammar
    help
    inference (package)
    internals
    lazyimport
    metrics (package)
    misc (package)
    model (package)
    parse (package)
    probability
    sem (package)
    sourcedstring
    stem (package)
    tag (package)
    test (package)
    text
    tokenize (package)
    toolbox
    tree
    treetransforms
    util
    yamltags

FILE
    c:\python32\lib\site-packages\nltk
```

More details [here](https://www.nltk.org/data.html)